# If else statement with a string compare java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, equals-operator

I am very new to java code, only ever really used C++ before. 
I am trying to compare two string variables and if they match set a new variable to string answer else new variable would be null.

e.g.

```
if (ID.equals(DeviceID)){
        MobileDevice = "BB 9630";
     else
        MobileDevice = null;
     end if
```

But this does not seem to work when I try it, and I think the logic is correct...any help?

Comment: Apart from the use of `.equals()` the code is the same in Java as C++.

Comment: -1 for cluttering stackoverflow. Just read few first chapters of some java book or tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to do this is to use a tri-graph, something you can do in C++ as well.

```
String mobileDevice = id.equals(deviceId) ? "BB 9630" : "unknown";
```

You should use `camelCase` for variables in Java.

Answer (score 1):

u need to correct your syntax.

```
     if (ID.equals(DeviceID)){
        MobileDevice = "BB 9630";
     }else{
        MobileDevice = null;
     }
```

Comment: There also is no "end if" in C++.

Comment: C++ doesn't have `end if` either.

Comment: it was a kind of algorithm but ok thanks

Comment: The last time I saw an `End If` was in Visual Basic 6 :|

Comment: @Kon Along with `IsTrue(x)` ;)

Comment: Just a code review. I prefer (sorry for lack of formatting)        MobileDevice = null;                                               if (ID.equals(DeviceID) ) {                                MobileDevice = "..."; }

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is just wrong for Java:

```
if (ID.equals(DeviceID)) {
    MobileDevice = "BB 9630";
}
else {
    MobileDevice = null;
}
```

Note the lack of end-if. Also you only need curly braces { } around multiple statements in an if-else block. For example, if you wanted to do two things:

```
if (a == 1) {
    //First action
    //Next action
    //So on..
}
```

Comment: My mistake, thanks for noticing that.